Did Goldoni decide to set the action of "La bottega del caffè" during a Venetian carnival for the sake of verisimilitude?
I know that Goldoni is the great reformer of Italian theater, who transformed the 'commedia dell'arte' into

true and ‘modern’ theatre texts, entirely scripted, with the various roles defined and assigned, line after line.

As stated in the Booklet from Carlo Goldoni's House museum, this is what Goldoni's plays represented:

No more ribaldry and weird plots, no more stock lines, few or no masks: enlightened and bourgeois, modern theatre was born at last.

Realism is an essential component in Goldoni's modern theater. Goldoni himself writes in the preamble to La bottega del caffè titled "L'autore a chi legge" ("The author to the reader"):

I miei caratteri sono umani, sono verisimili, e forse veri, ma io li traggo dalla turba universale degli uomini, e vuole il caso che alcuno in essi si riconosca. Quando ciò accade, non è mia colpa che il carattere tristo a quel vizioso somigli; ma colpa è del vizioso, che dal carattere ch'io dipingo, trovasi per sua sventura attaccato.

This is translated by Robert Cornthwaite this way:

My characters are human, they are lifelike, and possibly
true; but I draw them from the universal crowd of mankind.
and chance will have it that some individual among them
may recognize himself. When this happens, it is not my fault
if the wretched character I drew resembles that particular
wicked individual; no, it's the fault of the wicked individual
that from the character I depict he finds himself by his own
misadventure tarred with the same brush.

During the 18th-century Venetian carnival, numerous theater performances were staged, and indeed, prior to its printing, La bottega del caffè was performed several times in Venice during the carnival of 1751.
The fact is that the action of La bottega del caffè takes place during a Venetian carnival from the time of Goldoni, as we can see in several scenes. For instance, in the XIVth scene of Act I, Eugenio says to Placida:

Dovreste far così. Siamo ora di carnovale, dovreste mascherarvi, e così più facilmente lo trovereste.

This is rendered this way Cornthwaite's translation:

It's carnival time–wear a mask. That way you can catch him unawares.

In the XVIIth scene of Act I and the XXIst scene of Act II, we see how Vittoria is masked. And in the XXth secene of Act II, Lisaura says

Dopo pranzo vedremo le maschere

which is translated by Cornthwaite as

And the maskers in the carnival.

Notice that Cornthwaite's translations are not literal at all.
This made me think about the verisimilitude of classical French theater (note that Goldoni uses the adjective verisimile in his preamble), where the aim was for the audience to immerse themselves in what was being portrayed, feeling as though they were truly present on the stage. Thus, thinking about Venetian audience during carnival performances of the play,
my question would be: the fact that the action of La bottega del caffè is set during a Venetian carnival was intended for the sake of verisimilitude?

I don't know the play, but presumably Goldoni thought that the Venetian carnival would make a great setting for his story! Verisimilitude  refers to the realistic way in which the characters behave.

@KateBunting:  I mean "verisimilitude" in the sense this concept had in French classical theater (Racine, for instance). In French classical tragedies, this was essential to achieve catharsis. Of course, Goldoni wasn't seeking catharsis in his comedy, but it seems to me that he was aiming for the spectator to have the impression of being living everything was happening on the stage.

Even so, surely that's about the way the play was written, not the choice of setting?
